# Entity Framework's DbContext Lifetime in Worker Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-worker-roles

I have worker role that does some work with the database every second.

Is it ok to initialize the `DbContext` when the worker is started and use it throughout the lifetime of the worker?

How is the db connection handled? What if the database goes offline and back online? Will I still be able to use the context?

Comment: Too broad, too vague. There are two questions in the first place. Then, the first one depends largely on what you do in the worker role, on how many data, for how long. For the second question you should look at connection resilience with Entity Framework.

Comment: @GertArnold The question is about using a single `DbContext` instance in a worker role. The other questions are things I'm worried about in this regard. "for how long" - "throughout the lifetime of the worker". This means from VM startup to VM shutdown, no? "connection resilience" - are you saying that a connection loss is a transient failure and will be dealt with by the retry logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to create, use and destroy the context for each operation... do not hang onto it.
I used to worry at first because I had no idea how expensive it was to create the DbContext, the answer is, not very.

If you attempt to keep reusing a DbContext instance you will also run into problems (very quickly) as it's internal state models will start reporting conflicts for versions of the object that have been loaded (updated whatever) previously

Comment: I accept this answer because it is correct but see also the expanded explanation in my answer.

Comment: This article suggests setting up DbContext in OnStart() and using inside Run(): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/#create-the-application-from-scratch. That's not to say it's correct but just FYI

Comment: That article is dealing with Azure Cloud Storage from what I can see, not Entity Framework on a local disk. On some systems dealing with network communication it *can* be preferable to initialise the connection and keep it open, but that depends on the amount of handshake that needs to be done (i.e. HTTP does not work that way). So I think you need to be careful not to mix concepts here as the backbone (and therefore operation) will be wildly different between the two. Cheers, Paul

Answer (score 2):

To my best current knowledge, the main `DbContext` abstraction is the unit of work.

DbContext opens and closes a db connection whenever it needs to (i.e. on `context.SaveChanges()`) so the db connection is irrelevant to the context's scope.

Looking at that this way, I now think that to decide what should be the scope of the `DbContext` instance you need to think of your unit of work and the entities it manages in memory.

For example, it my question, usually it will not make sense using a single context instance throughout the lifetime of the worker because:

1. Usually you will work on different entities in each role invocation. In this case, the context will need to load these entities into memory anyway.
2. Overtime, the context will manage more and more entities in memory which will cause performance problems (as it scans the graph looking for changes and things to do) and ultimately result in memory problems.
3. Keeping entities in memory for a long time increases the chances of inconsistencies between the entities in the context and the actual data in the db. Resolving these inconsistencies can cost in performance.

To summarize, it is probably wrong to use the same `DbContext` instance throughout the lifetime of the worker role.

To decide on the scope of a `DbContext` think in terms of the unit of work you're implementing.